# How do I actually apply values from SASS List/Maps to elements?

Tags: sass

I've inherited a project and it has a variable list/map in its scss file, which has:

```
$palette: (
  success: #53a646,
  warning: #faa41a,
  alert: #ec5840,
);
```

I want to use one of these variables (`warning`) and apply it to an element. I've googled but have not been able to find a way to apply it.

I've seen examples like:

```
.warning-btn {
 background-color: nth($palette, 2); 
}
```

But this isn't working for me.

Would anyone know the correct way of applying the variable to an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to the following

```
$palette: (
  success: #53a646,
  warning: #faa41a,
  alert: #ec5840,
);
.warning-btn {
 background-color:#{map-get($palette,warning)}
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That's it thanks! But how is that meant to save time? Why would you use it this way?

Comment: Maps are like hash sets with key value pairs search time would be easy ...for better understanding you can refer this https://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-maps/